# Perl regex - can I say 'if character/string matches, delete it and all to right of it'?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have an array of strings, some of which contain the character '-'. I want to be able to search for it and for those strings that contain it I wish to delete all characters to the right of it.

So for example if I have:

```
$string1 = 'home - London';
$string2 = 'office';
$string3 = 'friend-Manchester';
```

or something as such, then the affected strings would become:

```
$string1 = 'home';
$string3 = 'friend';
```

I don't know if the white-space before the '-' would be included in the string afterwards (I don't want it as I will be comparing strings at a later point, although if it doesn't affect string comparisons then it doesn't matter).

I do know that I can search and replace specific strings/characters using something like:

```
$string1 =~ s/-//
or 
$string1 =~ tr/-//
```

but I'm not very familiar with regular expressions in Perl so I'm not 100% sure of these. I've looked around and couldn't see anything to do with `'to the right of'` in regex. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete anything after a hyphen `-` with this substitution:

```
s/-.*$//s
```

However, you will want to remove the whitespace prior to the hyphen and thus do

```
s/\s* - .* $//xs
```

The `$` anchores the regex at the end of the string and the `/s` flag allows the dot to match newlines as well. While the `$` is superfluous, it might add clarity.

Your substitution would just have removed the first `-`, and your transliteration would have removed all hyphens from the string.

Comment: both answers good ~ this one has a bit more to it but +1 for each :)

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expressions are just searching for the dash, so that's all they replace. You want to search for the dash, and anything after it.

```
$string =~ s/-.*//;
```

. represents any character, * means search for that character 0 or more times, and match as many as possible (i.e. to the end of the string if possible)

You can also search for an optional space before it.

```
$string =~ s/\s?-.*//;
```

(\s is a clearer way to specify a space character)

Comment: To make your space optional, append a `?` to it.

Answer (score 3):

Using plain `substr()` and `index()` is possible as well.

```
my @strings = ("we are - so cool",
               "lonely",
               "friend-Manchester",
               "home - london",
               "home-new york",
               "home with-childeren-first episode");
local $/ = " ";
foreach (@strings) {
  $_ = substr($_,0,index($_,'-')) if (index($_,'-') != -1);
  chomp;
}
```

Comment: what exactly makes this look-ahead? Is it simply that you do not have the `$string =~` stage?

Comment: actually, I decided to change it to substr() and index() as this was not shown yet... [-:

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good.  However, in light of what you said:

> ...if it doesn't affect string comparisons then it doesn't matter

You don't need a separate step for this at all.  Suppose you want to compare `$string`with another variable, `$search_string`.  The following expression will check for an exact match, except that it ignores anything `$string` has after a dash:

```
if ($string =~ /^$search_string(\s*-|$)/) { print "Strings matched"; }
```

Comment: Since the OP seemed to indicate this would be a string to string comparison latter `$search_string` would need to be quoted to ensure it isn't treated as a regex: `/^\Q$search_string\E(\s*-|$)/`

Answer (score 0):

`#Using Regex:`

```
my @strings = 
("we are - so cool",
"lonely",
"friend - Manchester",
"home - london",
"home - new york",
"home with-childeren-first episode"
);

foreach (@strings) {
$_ =~ s/-\s*[a-zA-Z ]+\s*//g;
print "NEW: ".$_."\n";
}
```